# Making a file in C++ with permissions that only the user can see the file and edit it

Tags: c++, c, windows, permissions

I would like to make a file that only my program has permissions to write in/read/visualize the file, in windows 7 we have those permissions but I don't know how to make from a user that I create, the user will be only my executable, only it can see, read and write in the file.

I saw a program doing that, but I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance, I'm sorry for not posting code, because it wouldn't be helpful since I don't know how to deal with permissions in windows via C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't restrict file access to only your app. You can only restrict access to specific user accounts and/or groups. Look at the `SetFileSecurity()` and `SetNamedSecurityInfo()` functions for that. If a suitable user account with adequate permissions runs your app (or any app for that matter), or your app (or another app)  impersonates such an account, it will be able to access the file.

Comment: That's really what I've been looking for, to set a random user for the file and be able to impersonate it via my application. Do you know any way to do that? what should I read or do to implement that ?

Comment: Create a DACL with the desired user permissions, apply them to the file, then use `LogonUser()` and `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()` to impersonate a user when needed.

Comment: Be warned that a competent user will be able to extract the credentials you are using to log into the special account with.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions in windows are based on the user and not the application. Hence you can't restrict the access to a file to a specific program / executable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that if you separate the file access functionality into a different executable and install it as a service, but it would be a lot of work, and you would have to secure the API to that service anyway.

I would recommend you to encrypt the contents of your file instead.